# javascript: Callback function code considered as string

Tags: javascript

Am a newbie in javascript, please help me understand below case where the callback function code is being considered as a string and passed as argument instead of passing the value of the callback function as an argument:

```js
//Case3: Create Callback function in the argument section of calling statement.

function child3(callback,arg2=3) {
     return console.log("Case3: callback function - parent function out:", callback+arg2,"\n");
}

child3(parent3=()=>{
   let a=1;
   let b=1;
   return a+b;
},2);
```

*Output:*

```
Case3: callback function - parent function out: ()=>{
   let a=1;
   let b=1;
   return a+b;
}2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `+`, there are two possibilities:

- If both operands are numbers or BigInts, they are added together
- Otherwise, both operands are concatenated together into a string

If you do

```
callback+arg2
```

and `callback` isn't a number, the result will be a concatenation of it and `arg2`. In your code, `callback` is not a number; it's a function. You probably wanted to *call* the callback instead of concatenating it - eg, `callback()`.

Another issue is that

```
child3(parent3=()=>{
```

should almost certainly be

```
child3(()=>{
```

unless you deliberately wanted to *both* create a new global function named `parent3` *and* pass that to `child3`.

```js
function child3(callback, arg2 = 3) {
  console.log(callback() + arg2);
}

child3(() => {
  let a = 1;
  let b = 1;
  return a + b;
}, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a string, but a parameter. It has a name in the `function`'s parameter list, which is `callback`, so, inside the `function` it is referred to as `callback` and when you pass

```
"Case3: callback function - parent function out:", callback+arg2,"\n"
```

to `console.log`, you convert the function to string. By the way, you can do that without passing the function as parameter as well

```js
function foo(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

console.log(foo);
```

So, you do not pass it as a string, you pass it as a function instead, but it is converted into a string, i.e. the function definition when you call `console.log`.